# Making an abstract class in kotlin communicate its responsibilities better to its children

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, inheritance

I've been considering a few solutions for reducing boilerplate in a large number of fragments that have the same patterns and workflows.

The best solution I've come up with is to abstract a lot of the standard tasks into an abstract class and then force the implementing fragments to override methods that determine the unique flavor for their particular context.

For the sake of providing an example, here's something I'm making up to illustrate the problem.

```
abstract class ContainsRepetiveBoilerPlate<T:View,U:InfoForView>:Fragment(){
fun performNinetyPercentOfTheWork(){//tedious stuff that's always the same}
val thingThatChildMightWantToAccess=mutableListOf<U>()
fun upDateUsefullThing(){//update thingThatChildMightWantToAccess}
abstract fun fullFillContractToBindViewToItsInformation(t:T,u:U)
}
```

Now the fragment will look like this:

```
class HasATTypeViewPopulatedFromAUTypeDataClass:ContainsRepetitiveBoilerplate<T,U>(){

override fun fullfillContractToBindViewToItsInformation(t:T,u:U){//for every view inside of T, give it values from u}
```

Setting aside just for one moment the *why*, of which there are many. I'm interested to know any *how*s for forcing the child to somehow acknowledge that it's aware of `thingThatChildMightWantToAccess`.

Likewise, what tools are available to force the child to call `performNinetyPercentOfTheWork()`?

I've seen a couple of good ideas surrounding making `performNinetyPercentOfTheWork()` include a call to an abstract fun. But it would be awesome if I could make the linter complain if the child never calls it.

Here's a really really stupid solution that isn't at all serious but would help you understand what I want to achieve.

```
abstract class ContainsRepetiveBoilerPlate<T:View,U:InfoForView>:Fragment(){
var hasBeenCalled=false
fun performNinetyPercentOfTheWork(){hasbeenCalled=true //do other stuff}
val thingThatChildMightWantToAccess=mutableListOf<U>()
fun upDateUsefullThing(){//update thingThatChildMightWantToAccess}
abstract fun fullFillContractToBindViewToItsInformation(t:T,u:U)
override fun onViewCreated(){
    toBeInvokedDuringOnViewCreated()
    if (!hasBeenCalled){throw Error("you need to call performNinetyPercentOfTheWork()"}
abstract fun toBeInvokedDuringOnViewCreated()
}
```

Ok, here's an even stupider example, solely for the sake of trying to illustrate the functionality that I want from the linter.

```
abstract class ContainsRepetiveBoilerPlate<T:View,U:InfoForView>:Fragment(){
var hasBeenCalled=false
fun performNinetyPercentOfTheWork(){hasbeenCalled=true //do other stuff}
val thingThatChildMightWantToAccess=mutableListOf<U>()
fun upDateUsefullThing(){//update thingThatChildMightWantToAccess}
abstract fun fullFillContractToBindViewToItsInformation(t:T,u:U)
abstract fun acknowledgeThatYouKnowAboutUsefullVariable():Boolean
}
```

You can see from these examples that I'm not being serious. I just really want for their to be a way for me to make my abstract class be more expressive about what it can provide to its children, and what liberties its taken to handle the child's responsibilities.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but this is uncommon to require a specific behavior of the subclass/a user of a class. The requirement to implement all abstract methods is usually enough. Of course, class can verify if it is used according to its contract, but what you described is like a hammer requiring its user to hit nails it has chosen to hit. And actually, classes are very expressive and explicit about what they provide to subtypes - protected/public members.

Comment: Also, it is usually better to use composition over inheritance. I mean, instead of sharing common behavior by subtyping, it would be better to extract shared code to separate classes and use them in all fragments. This is much easier to maintain in a long term.

Comment: One final (I hope ;-) ) note: depending on your case, you could consider inverting the control between base and subclass. Base would be in control of the whole operation from the beginning to the end and it would ask its subclass for some data or to perform some tasks through abstract methods or callbacks. Of course, it would make this class less flexible, but I guess this is what you ask for.

Comment: I'm thinking wrapping the behavior into a third class would probably be the most expressive. Like if I created ```HandlesRepetiveBoilerPlate()``` and made it do all of the work, then I would get tab completion and method hinting from that. Then as long as the child instantiates it, they would know what responsibilities it's handling and know what properties it has available. If I really wanted to, I could make an interface that just adds a requirement to instantiate the handler. Probably overkill. But either way, a handler class seems more expressive.

Comment: I think @broot is heading down the right path. Included an answer to try and clearly define it.

Comment: Added a more flexible composition example to the answer, because we should prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement of wanting the "linter" to complain about the fact that some code does not execute some other code (which is just another way of saying make the compiler complain) would require the compiler to know all possible paths of execution a program can take, and then you run into the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

So, the best you can hope for is run time errors or warnings. Where you implement something that checks that a particular thing has been done and if it has not error.

Or, make sure it happens with something like the [template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Here is a generic inheritance example:

```
interface LifeCycleAware {
    fun stage1()
}

abstract class LifeCycleTemplate : LifeCycleAware {

    /**
     * Implementations can access this state
     */
    protected var stateFromStage1: String? = null

    /**
     * A template pattern implementation of the lifecycle hook.
     */
    override fun stage1() {
        startStage1()
        doCustomStage1Stuff()
        endStage1()
    }

    protected abstract fun doCustomStage1Stuff()

    private fun startStage1() {
        stateFromStage1 = "starting-stage-1"
    }

    private fun endStage1() {
        stateFromStage1 = "ended-stage-1"
    }
}
```

Or a more flexible composition example:

```
typealias InternalStep = (me: LifeCycleComposition) -> Unit

class LifeCycleComposition(
    private val customStage1: InternalStep,
    private val startStage1: InternalStep = { me -> me.stateFromStage1 = "starting-stage-1" },
    private val endStage1: InternalStep = { me -> me.stateFromStage1 = "ended-stage-1" }
) : LifeCycleAware {

    /**
     * Implementations can access this state
     */
    internal var stateFromStage1: String? = null

    /**
     * A template pattern implementation of the lifecycle hook.
     */
    override fun stage1() {
        startStage1(this)
        customStage1(this)
        endStage1(this)
    }
}
```